# How to save image in temp folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

For taking the DIV screenshot is used domtoimage.js File,

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/38/how-to-capture-an-image-from-a-dom-element-with-javascript 
by using this file is download but how to save that file into temp folder before download.

```
function exportAsImage(){
    var result= $('#dashboardChartData').text();
    var nameOfChart=$('#exportAsImage').val();
    var node = document.getElementById("dashboardChartData");

    if(result.trim()!="No Data Available."){
        $('#simplemodal-overlay').css('display','block');     
        domtoimage.toPng(node).then(function(dataUrl) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = dataUrl;
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download =  nameOfChart+".png";  
            $('#simplemodal-overlay').css('display','none');
            link.href = img.src;        
            localStorage.setItem(img.src, link.download );
            link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(`click`, {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
            link.remove();
        });
    } else {
        bootbox.alert({ 
            size: 'small',
            title :'Alert',
            message: "No Data Available", 
        });     
    }   
}
```

Comment: you cannot do that

Comment: Browsers do not have access to the device's filesystem. You don't even know if a specific folder name exists on the device, or where in the hierarchy it might be - that varies greatly by operating-system in any case. The user controls whether to accept the download at all, and if so, where to store it. This restriction exists for security. think about it for a moment: would you be happy if websites could store any random file on your disk without your permission??

Comment: Thanks for reply sir,
can we save that image in local dir in ecllipse ...